# EventListeners for custom Listview with buttons

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I already spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem, I've seen a lot other StackOverflow Posts about this topic but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

I have a ListActivity and a custom ArrayAdapter. There are several buttons in my listview for example a delete button. However the onItemClick method would only be invoked if the TextView of the list is clicked. I can add OnClickListeners to the buttons, but then I have the problem that I don't know the position of the element to which the button belongs. I know I could set tags for every single button, but there has to be a better way of doing it!

This is my adapter:

```
    private class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private int countItems = 0;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context ctx, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> itemList){
        super(ctx, textViewResourceId, itemList);
        this.items = itemList;  
        this.countItems = itemList.size();
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return countItems;
    }

    public Item getItem(int pos){
        return itemList.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        //Get the current list item
        final Item currentItem = itemList.get(position);

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlist_item_row, null);
        }
        Item item = items.get(position);
        if (item != null){
            TextView bt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.bt_itemlist_item);
            if (bt != null){
                bt.setText(item.getName());
            }
        }
        return row;
    }

}
```

Would be great if someone could tell me the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `OnClickListeners` for `Buttons` in `getView()` and you'll get the position

Comment: How can I access the position? If I create a new anonymous OnClickListener inside the getView method I cannot read the position. I get : Cannot refer to a non-final variable position inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: You can set the position as final in the signature. The compiler will not block you

Comment: Hmm could have tried that before :S
Thanks a lot Nathan, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Just like you did bt.setText(item.getName()), why dont you get a reference to the delete button and then set the on click listener to it.
You will be adding the on click listener in getView method, and you will automatically get the position of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  Setting the tag of a View is pretty common, but if you don't want to set the tag of many views, just use the parent (if possible). For the variable `row` that you return, set the tag to your Item, `currentItem`.  Otherwise, just set the tag of each clickable View.

For each of your click actions, you can actually use 1 instance of the click listener, and simply check the tag of the view's parent.  For example, make 1 instance of `View.OnClickListener` for every delete button in your layout.  In the `onClick()` method, check the tag of the parent View, and get the `Item` instance that should be deleted.

```
private class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
{

    View.OnClickListener deleteListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            View parent = (View)view.getParent();
            Item item = (Item)parent.getTag();
            //Do something with "item"
        }
    };

    //Remainder omitted

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        //Remainder omitted
        row.setTag(currentItem);
        View deleteButton; //find this somewhere in your layout
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(deleteListener);

        return row;
    }

}
```